# Multiply vectors stored in two multidimensional arrays without for loop in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

```
%In MATLAB: I have stored vectors A and B in two multidim. arrays:
A = rand(4,1,4); B= rand(1,3,4);

%Now I want to create multidim array C(3,3,4) 
%by multiply A and B in each dim i (:,:,i) without a for-loop.

%So instead of these four operations below, just perform one operation e.g. C=A*B.

C(:,:,1)=A(:,:,1)*B(:,:,1);
C(:,:,2)=A(:,:,2)*B(:,:,2);
C(:,:,3)=A(:,:,3)*B(:,:,3);
C(:,:,4)=A(:,:,4)*B(:,:,4);
```

I tried bsxfun, but could not find any suitable operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array multiply with `bsxfun`

```
C = bsxfun(@times,A,B)
```

Comment: That's a new one on me. I had to look at it twice before I figured out what was going on. Very nice.